# Validações do Command - CQRS

Tags: design-pattern, ddd, cqrs

Estou aprendendo sobre CQRS e em um Hangout promovido por um MVP da Micrososft ele apresentou uma implementação de `Command` em que há validações dos dados do modelo dentro da validação do `Command`. Validações de datas ou se há campos obrigatórios em branco, por exemplo, não estavam no modelo tornando a entidade de modelo quase anêmica. Aí me veio as dúvidas, que apesar da explicação do MVP que pra mim não foi muito convincente.

É realmente uma boa prática implementar validação do modelo dentro da validação do `Command` ?

Exemplo da abordagem usada no Hungout:

```
public abstract class UserCommand : Command
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public string Email { get; protected set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; protected set; }
}

public class RegisterNewUserCommand : UserCommand
{
    public RegisterNewUserCommand(string name, string email, DateTime birthDate)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
        BirthDate = birthDate;
    }

    public override bool IsValid()
    {
        ValidationResult = new RegisterNewUserCommandValidation().Validate(this);
        return ValidationResult.IsValid;
    }
}


public class RegisterNewUserCommand : UserCommand
{

 public class RegisterNewUserCommandValidation : UserValidation<RegisterNewUserCommand>
{
    public RegisterNewUserCommandValidation()
    {
        ValidateName();
        ValidateBirthDate();
        ValidateEmail();
    }
}
```

O que realmente é feito dentro da validação de um `COMMAND`?

Permissão para execução do `Command`, existência de duplicidade seriam exemplo de validação ?

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: @Maniero adicione trechos de códigos que exemplificam a questão...

Answer (score 0):

As validações variam de acordo com a aplicação e com os dados a serem validados.

Se, por exemplo, tu tens um formulário para cadastro de cliente em um e-commerce, tu precisarias, por exemplo, validar o CPF (documento) da pessoa, se as datas estão no formato correto, se os campos obrigatórios foram preenchidos. Tu ainda poderias validar se o endereço cadastrado existe com uma integração com alguma API (Correios, Google Maps, etc). Também, na hora de efetivar uma compra, é necessário validar cartão de crédito, cupom de desconto, etc...

Essas validações se extendem - poderias validar permissões de acessos a determinados dados, credenciais de usuários, criptografia, etc.

Em resumo - são validações para ver se os dados contidos no objeto estão corretos para prosseguir com o comando...

No exemplo de código dado, a validação é se os dados estão corretos para criação de um usuário. Poderiam estar vendo se não há duplicatas, se os campos estão em branco, etc...